# How to check if a value is empty and return dummy text like NA

Tags: html, laravel, input-field

I have a input field that has data pulling form the database, however when the data base is empty the input field displays the disabled that is used to disable the field when not editable.

For example in my html:

```
<label for="fname">CompanyCode:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value={{$id->CompanyCode}} disabled>
```

This above pulls data however if there is now data to pull it uses the "disabled" word as the value and then the field doesn't become disabled.

Can I use a condition to overcome this using something like:

```
<label for="fname">CompanyCode:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" 
                 value= @if($id->CompanyCode) count() == 0)
                 <td colspan="5" class="text-center"> Nothing Found </td>
                @endif
                    disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer :

```
<label for="fname">CompanyCode:</label 
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="{{ $id->CompanyCode}}" {{$id->companyCode ? '' : 'disabled' }}>
```

I could have also added Quotations for the desired result aswell :

```
<label for="fname">CompanyCode:</label 

<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="{{ $id->CompanyCode }}" disabled>
```